# Pasting text from chosen .txt file into cells (script)

Tags: google-apps-script

I wanted to make a script in google sheets that would allow me to copy&paste the contents of a exported whatsapp conversation (txt file) and paste it in the A1 cell.

It works no problem if I manually go to the A1 cell, click File>Import>Upload the file>Complete the import with the appropriate available settings.

I even tried recording the macro but whilst I upload the files, nothing is recorded.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should do more research or make an attempt at some code before posting. However, I  happen to have a procedure for converting text to a clean singular cell value. You need to have the text file uploaded to google drive already and grab the file ID which can be found in the URL to view/share etc.

```
function textToExcel() {
  // you will need the url of the file 
  //as example:
  //  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c???something??????/view

  const zFileID = "1c???something??????";//capture the middle string area after the d/ and before the /view
  const zText = DriveApp.getFileById(zFileID).getBlob().getDataAsString();

  var zSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  zSS.getRange("A1").setValue(zText); // change to where you want text
}
```